# CPack: Interface include directories are missing in archive

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I am using CMake 3.10.1 and trying to use CPack to generate archives for a library and I cannot get it to add the interface include directory to the archive.

The library and the generated export files are added as expected, however the include directory (added using `target_include_directories(... PUBLIC ...)` is missing entirely.

The `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Test VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED foo.cpp) #add sources and executable

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc>  
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:inc>
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}
    INCLUDES DESTINATION inc
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION inc
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
)
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION .)

include(CPack)
```

The contents of my source dir:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── foo.cpp
└── inc
    └── foo.h
```

The contents of the tgz generated by `cpack -G TGZ .`

```
├── lib
│   └── libTest.so
├── Test.cmake
└── Test-noconfig.cmake
```

Any ideas why it could be missing the `inc` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator-like expression `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` used in the `target_include_directories()` command by itself doesn't *install* corresponded directory. You need to install this directory manually (with `install(FILES)` or `install(DIRECTORY)`).

---

Expression `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` specifies interface include directory for the target in the config file, which exports *install* tree (see `install(EXPORT)` command).

Expression `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` specified interface include directory for the target in the project itself, and in the config file which exports build tree (see `EXPORT()` command).

But these expressions doesn't enforce `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` directory to be copied into `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` one on installation. As opposite, content of this directories usually differs: aside from header files for outer use, installed into `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` directory, a directory `$<BUILD_INTERFACE>` may contain header files for project's internal use, which are not installed.

Comment: Though the generator expression isn't relevant in this case, I was under the impression that the `PUBLIC_HEADER` or `INCLUDES` property can be used to install the directories set in `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. Upon a more detailed review of the documentation this does not see to be the case, thank you for the hint!